# Calculating aspect in flat areas in ASTER DEM with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, aster

I have an analyzed aspect surface from ASTER DEM 30m resolution in ArcGIS 10.2. But it shows many aspects in flat area.[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExC9R.jpg]Normaly it must calculate this are as flat (-1). How can I resolve this problem?